# mount does not work after migration to 18.04

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

after migrating to xubuntu 18.04 CIFS mounting of my synology folders does not work. Similar problem occurs with 2 desktops on our local network.
synology samba version is 4.4.9. Linux Xubuntu desktops are 18.04 and therefore use Samba 4.7.6-ubuntu.
Journalctl indicates:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1256]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1256]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1245]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1245]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1259]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1259]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1243]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC mount[1243]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
août 21 17:25:23 odile-GE72-2QC systemd[1]: media-music.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
```

ANy suggestion would be most welcomed.

Comment: Before the above messages there is :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to answer the question since you didn't post the mount command you used to connect to the server. So I am going to guess:

The version of samba you are using is not relevant because a CIFS mount is Linux kernel based. What is relevant is the version of the Linux kernel you are using.

Before kernel 4.13 CIFS defaulted to using SMB1 to connect to the server. The version of the kernel in 18.04 is set to negotiate the SMB dialect from SMB2.1 to SMB3.

So if your NAS is set up to only use SMB1 add an option to your cifs mount: **vers=1.0** Or you can modify your NAS to go up to SMB3.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had same problem. In early 2018, a bug was introduced in Linux kernel that affects server DNS lookup. If you replace name with IP number in your mount command, and if you get vers argument correct, problem may be solved.

See https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-cifs/msg13825.html for DNS bug. Issue has prevented me from accessing cifs shares in Fedora and Ubuntu for most of the year.